# C# Datatable LINQ join returns empty collection

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have this code:

```
var intersected = from cardRow in dt1.AsEnumerable()
            join stagingRow in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                on cardRow["CA_NUMBER"].ToString().ToLower() equals 
                dataRetriever.GetCardNumberFromStgValue(stagingRow).ToLower()
            select new ValidityEntity
            {
                OPR_TYPE = stagingRow["col1"].ToString(),
                STATUS_LVL = cardRow["col2"].ToString(),
                CARD_NUMBER = cardRow["CA_NUMBER"].ToString()
            };
```

However this returns an empty row collection (to be clear - there are no items in the collection), though I know that there are records that have the same CA_NUMBER.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: You get empty records or no records at all?

Comment: no records at all.. intersected.Count() == 0

Comment: does a left join work? I mean just try to locate the error. I suppose it's the condition in your `on` clause

Comment: @ASh - It is used in the join condition as a parameter to a function

Comment: @rbr94 - The above code isnt already a left inner join?

Comment: No it's a inner join. You got only rows that match your join condition

Comment: Why do you need the method `GetCardNumberFromStgValue` for the second table's rows but not for the first one? You say that both tables have the same `CA_NUMBER`, but why don't you also use `stagingRow["CA_NUMBER"]`? Do you get a result if you use `on cardRow["CA_NUMBER"].ToString().ToLower() equals stagingRow["CA_NUMBER"].ToString().ToLower()`

Comment: @TimSchmelter i must use this function because the second table doesnt have this column. Its CA_NUMBER value is hidden in a binary value in one of the columns, which is why i use this function to retrieve the CA_NUMBER (which it does successfully)

Comment: @TimSchmelter The function itself work great, i debugged it and i know it returns the correct value

Comment: Currently we can't help to solve this issue because the code works. It will join two DataRows by this value and returns a `ValidityEntity` every time. You say that there are equal values but apparently they aren't equal.

Comment: Does this return true or false: `dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("CA_NUMBER")).Intersect(dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(r => dataRetriever.GetCardNumberFromStgValue(r)), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Any()`. That is the correct way to perform a case insensitive comparison and to prevent culture related issues. Maybe you should also add a `Trim()` to remove leading and trailing zeros.